# Is pstree available on all Unices and Linux operating systems?

Tags: ps, portability

Is it a standard command that I can be assured is available on all standard-conformant operating systems?  If so, what is the guarantee given by the relevant standard?

Is it, conversely, a non-standard command that is nonetheless widely available?

On what (Unix and Linux, of course) operating systems can I find a `pstree` command available, either as part of the operating system or as a package from the operating system's normal package repositories?

Comment: The package that pstree is typically included in is `psmisc` - https://pkgs.org/download/psmisc. It's intrinsically difficult to determine if utility X is installed by default on *ixes Y.

Comment: It’s a good edit to the question, but I fear would have too broad an answer as time goes on.  It’s the last question in the Question that pushes it over the edge for me.

Comment: JdeBP thanks for the edit. @JeffSchaller  I don’t mind browsing through every distribution’s docs to find out if this exists, but for the most common utilities, I kinda sense that there is some spec/convention being followed. My initial question was intended to find that. Do you think if the last question can be edited to ask the former, it might fit your criteria?

Comment: In *my* opinion, the best chance of specific question that can be concretely answered would be to ask which of these (X,Y,Z) *current* distributions include pstree in a default installation. I wouldn't expect an answerer to survey the hundreds (thousands?) of distributions, nor would I expect an answer to cover future distributions or ones that change their mind at some point. (1/2)

Comment: Also, you might consider whether a random UNIX variant has come up with their own `pstree` command that takes different options and/or does different things -- in which case you might want to specify which exact `pstree` you're curious about -- on the assumption that you're distributing a script that depends on certain pstree behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It's on Linux distros by default, on AIX or whatever you'd need to install/compile it.

Comment: Is there a place I can refer incase I need to find out about commands other than pstree? Also since you have enough reputation, could you please tage this question with pstree rather than ps? Thanks